# how to organize and simplify index file in php

Tags: php

hello I am using slim in PHP and every thing is well except my index contain to much code and is to messy. Now I want to create separate file and put some functions like register and login in that file and organize index file. I tried to make a separate php file and include my index like this:

```
<?php 
require './index.php';

$app->get('/test', function () use ($app) {
    echo "test";
});
?>
```

I know this approach is wrong, but really nothing else came to my mind and I could not find anything..

Answer (score 0):

From the [Slim documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html%20Slim%20documentation):

> Note that the second parameter is a callback. You could specify a Class (which need a __invoke() implementation) instead of a Closure. You can then do the mapping somewhere else:
>
> $app->any('/user', 'MyRestfulController');